# How to add glyphicon next to a basicContainerNode?

Tags: css, xpages, lotus-notes

Here is my xPage with a dropdown (basicContainerNode) that is a user name. I just want to add an icon next to that label. Assume I need to add it to IMAGE property but not to the label.

```
<xe:this.navbarUtilityLinks>
   <xe:basicContainerNode>
      <xe:this.label><![CDATA[#{javascript:var currentUserName:NotesName = session.createName(session.getEffectiveUserName());
        return "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-user' style='margin-right: 1em;'></span>" + currentUserName.getAbbreviated();}]]>
      </xe:this.label>

   <xe:this.children>
      <xe:loginTreeNode rendered="false"></xe:loginTreeNode>
      <xe:basicLeafNode title="Logout" submitValue="appLogout" label="Logout"></xe:basicLeafNode>
   </xe:this.children>
   </xe:basicContainerNode>
</xe:this.navbarUtilityLinks>
```

Answer (score 0):

basicContainerNode's label can be plain text only.

Remove the span-part from your label and add the following event to your XPage:

```
<xp:eventHandler
    event="onClientLoad"
    submit="false">
    <xp:this.script><![CDATA[dojo.query('.dropdown .dropdown-toggle').forEach(function(e){
        var spanNode = document.createElement("span");              
        spanNode.className = 'glyphicon glyphicon-user';
        spanNode.style.marginRight='1em';
        e.insertBefore(spanNode, e.firstChild);
    })]]></xp:this.script>
</xp:eventHandler>
```

It searches for classes "dropdown" + "dropdown-toggle" and inserts a span element with the classes "glyphicon glyphicon-user" and the style "margin-right: 1em".

[image]

This way you get the user icon before the username:

[image]